# How to fix docx and xlrd import error when using pyinstaller to make .py to .exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, docx

How to fix docx and xlrd import error when using pyinstaller to make .py to .exe?

```
# my-python-file.py
import xlrd    
import docx    
from docx.shared import Pt    
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
...
```

Use pyinstaller to convert into exe

```
pyinstaller my-python-file.py
```

When trying to run the resulting executable it gives import error

Comment: Please add the full error message. Which of the four imports results in the import error?

Comment: What is the error? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, every time i click the .exe, it appears and vanishes very fast. I cannot even see the error clearly. But I can some words about import error

Comment: Or any other ways to make .py to .exe when my .py has "docx" and "xlrd" needed to import?